# jquery mobile background does not fully extend to end of page

Tags: jquery-mobile

My jquery mobile background does quite extend to the end of the page. I'm testing this on my iphone in Mobile Safari. This white strip does not appear on my desktop. This same issue also does not occur when I test it on a Google Nexus' browser. Any ideas why this is happening?

I'm using this line of code in my css file to extend the background:

```
  [data-role=page]{height: 100% !important; position:relative !important;}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a footer overlaying the background? Have you inspected the element to see what the "computed" is?

Comment: @User970008 can't inspect because this only occurs on iphone sim and iphone device...thanks

Comment: Have you tried to set margin and padding for all elements to 0? I would start with trying to rule out any margin or padding that is getting added to your elements. This would just be for testing, and would help you figure out if it is a CSS interpretation happening by the browser. Then, you would just need to apply a zero margin to that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to set it to the height of the HTML document or the height of the viewport (initially viewable area), you could try:

```
$('#container').css('height', $(window).height());   // returns height of browser viewport
$('#container').css('height', $(document).height()); // returns height of HTML document
```